# The icon app android is small

Tags: android

i have a problem to display icon app. The icon show small. 
And the size is 128x128 px.
I tried different posibilities...
Somepeople suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean: the icon formats are [well documented](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html#size). Follow those instructions and you should be fine. You want the following 4 icons.

Launcher Icon Size  36 x 36 px  48 x 48 px  72 x 72 px  96 x 96 px

Answer (score 1):

Did youput the icon in the hdpi drawable folder?

Comment: then I would reccomend you to use the default Icon sizes. Or if you want to have an Icon with 128x128 create a new folder and name it:
drawable-xhdpi